# Why is my command line argument being interpreted as a Boolean (Perl 6)?

Tags: command-line, raku

Given this program:

```
#!/bin/env perl6
sub MAIN ($filename='test.fq', :$seed=floor(now) )
{
    say "Seed is $seed";
}
```

When I run it without any command line arguments, it works fine. However, when I give it a command line argument for `seed`, it says that its value is `True`:

```
./seed.p6 --seed 1234
Seed is True
```

Why is the number 1234 being interpreted as a boolean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl 6's MAIN argument handling plays well with gradual typing. Arguments can, and should be typecast to reduce ambiguity and improve validation:

```
#!/bin/env perl6                                                                                                                                    
sub MAIN (Str $filename='test.fq', Int :$seed=floor(now))
{
    say "Seed is $seed.";
}
```

After typecasting `seed` to `Int`, this option must be given a numeric argument and no longer defaults to a Boolean:

```
perl6 ./seed.pl -seed 1234
Usage:
  ./seed.pl [--seed=<Int>] [<filename>] 


perl6 ./seed.pl -seed=abc
Usage:
  ./seed.pl [--seed=<Int>] [<filename>] 


perl6 ./seed.pl -seed=1234
Seed is 1234.
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an `=` sign between your option `--seed` and its value `1234`:

```
./seed.p6 --seed=1234
```

Since you have a positional argument in your `MAIN` subroutine signature (i.e. `$filename`), the first argument not tied to an value with an `=` sign will be assigned to it.

Your original

```
./seed.p6 --seed 1234
```

was being interpreted as if `1234` were the filename (i.e. it was assigned to the variable `$filename`). Since a command line option without an argument is considered to be `True`, `$seed` was being assigned `True` in your original invocation of that script.

Comment: Other answers, comments, suggestions, and edits are all welcome.